# What do you do if you dont have a numpad

Tags: objects

imtrying to follow a tutorial on youtube but I have a laptop, and it doesent have a numpad, please help whats a good alternative

Answer (score 0):

On a mac, you can use the Funtion key (fn) + U or I or O or j or k or L or M.. please check this image:

[image: keyboard]